# vuejs bugfix debugging/deployment queries

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vuetify.js

I am being thrown a half backed, undocumented, non-handover project of VueJs with few other components as frontend and express as a backend. (Old developer who was maintaining things on git is abscond)

Backend/Express part I've figured it out most of the things but I got stuck on frontend part which is served using express_static

For VueJs I don't know what other things are depending

Is it using yarn or npm for build/deploy ?

**Using mostly command line**

1. What should be my starting point to look into project
2. Build/deploy  yarn <> npm is interchangeable.
3. Is it possible to convert Individual .vue file to .js file and deploy it?
4. What other tips and tricks you suggest for making quicker changes live on productions without major disaster (on front-end side).
5. What is the fastest way to hack things in this situation :)
6. Is there any docs what happen internally? - Curious to know!

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure any kind of Vue.js with Express tutorial will answer most of your questions. Vue is a pretty great frontend framework so I'd recommend giving it a go rather than trying to "hack things".

Comment: @SnakeyHips thanks. Going thru it, but what I am stuck at is less about Vue more about how the things structured for given project.